# How to add a keylistener to JFrame Subclass

Tags: java

I implemented all of the necessary methods and added the "implements KeyListener" and added the addKeyListener and setFocus(true) but I get no keyresponses. The JFrame includes a canvas class that I created. Here is the constructor for the window class.

```
    setBounds(0,0, width, height);
    setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    add(MainCanvas.Instance());
    this.getContentPane().addKeyListener(this);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);

    if (thread == null)
    {
        thread = new Thread(this);
    }

    thread.start();
```

Comment: what happens if you add the key listener to the MainCanvas.Instance() instead of to the content pane?

Comment: 1) If you acutally mean `Canvas`, swap that for a `JComponent` or `JPanel`.  Don't mix Swing and AWT (unless you know what you're doing, or are using Java 7).  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  3) The call to `setBounds(int, int, int, int)` is inadvisable, and made redundant by the call to `pack()` further down.

Answer (score 2):

Only the focus component will get sent the key events; you need to call `requestFocus()` on your `Canvas`.

Comment: And make sure that it's focusable property is set to true especially if it's a JPanel subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the KeyListener to the the Canvas instead of JFrame. When you add any component to JFrame (e.g. `add(MainCanvas.getInstance()`), with default layout (BorderLayout), the component occupies the JFrame view and all your key strokes are being sent to the Canvas and not to JFrame. Try adding the KeyListener to MainCanvas instead of JFrame.

Comment: I tried to add it to the canvas but it still didn't work. I put it in the add notifiy method after I set up the BufferStrategy and the constructor. (With all of the correct implementation).